# Assign category for each df row based on partial match with a string vector R

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching

I have

```
mydf <- data.frame(menu = c("chicken with peanut sauce", "sole and clam chowder", "shrimp salad"), category = NA)                
allergens1 <- c("peanut", "walnut", "cashew", "fava bean", "almond")
allergens2 <- c("scallops", "shrimp")
```

I would like to change category to an arbitrary string that I define (e.g. nuts) if any of the items in allergens are found in the menu strings. So the result would be:

```
menu                          category
chicken with peanut sauce      nuts
sole and clam chowder          NA
shrimp salad                   shellfish
```

The %in% operator does not seem to be helpful here as "mydf$menu %in% allergens" results in "False" "False" since the entire strings in menu do not match any of the items in allergens. I think grepl might be useful but not sure how to refer to the vector. I could code each item of the allergens vector in a search replace regex with "|" but I think there is probably a cleaner way to code this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep`/`grepl` here by pasting the string of `allergens1` and `allergens2` together as one pattern. If `menu` matches any item in `allergens1` we assign value `"nuts"` and if matches any item in `allergens2` we assign `"shellfish"` to `category`.

```
mydf$category[grep(paste0('\\b', allergens1, '\\b', collapse = '|'), mydf$menu)] <- 'nuts'
mydf$category[grep(paste0('\\b', allergens2, '\\b', collapse = '|'), mydf$menu)] <- 'shellfish'
mydf

#                       menu  category
#1 chicken with peanut sauce      nuts
#2     sole and clam chowder      <NA>
#3              shrimp salad shellfish
```

---

We can also use `case_when` with `str_detect` to do it in `tidyverse` way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

mydf %>%
  mutate(category  = case_when(
   str_detect(menu, str_c('\\b', allergens1, '\\b', collapse = '|'))~'nuts', 
   str_detect(menu, str_c('\\b', allergens2, '\\b', collapse = '|'))~'shellfish'))
```

We add word boundaries (`\\b`) to avoid matching  `"cashew"` with `"cashewnut"`. Remove them if you want them to be matched.

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to do. Appreciate seeing both the base and tidyverse versions.